# cURL doesn't seem to work in a while loop

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'll just post the whole thing since it would be a bit confusing otherwise:

```
<?php
echo "<html>
 <head>
  <title>ARMORY.</title>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset=iso-8859-1>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table width='50%' border='1' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='10'>";


$server = "Sunstrider";
$guild = "Mist";
$url='http://eu.wowarmory.com/guild-info.xml?r='.$server.'&gn='.$guild.'&p=1';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
$rosterxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
curl_close($ch);
$array = array();



foreach($rosterxml->guildInfo->guild->members->character as $char)
  if(strtolower($char['level']) === '80')
  {
        $array[] = $char['name']."<br />";

  }

  echo "
   <tr>
    <td valign='middle'>Name</td>
    <td valign='middle'>TEST</td>
   </tr>";  
$i = 0;
while($array[$i] != null) 
{

 $name = $array[$i];
 $raidurl='http://eu.wowarmory.com/character-achievements.xml?r='.$server.'&cn='.$name.'&c=168';
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $raidurl);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
 $xml2 = curl_exec($ch);
 $achievementxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml2);
 curl_close($ch);
 var_dump($achievement);

 echo "<tr>
  <td>$array[$i]</td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>";
 $i++;



}

?>

 </body>
</html>
```

That var_dump of $achievement just produces NULL over and over again (obviously due to the loop) instead of any information about the array. Doing a var_dump of $rosterxml produces the expected effect though, so cURL seems to work fine outside of the while loop.

Comment: Have you tested the URL it is attempting to access inside the loop?

Comment: See here how to handle curl errors : http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: I still like the `libxml_set_streams_context()` anti-user-agent-sniffing solution  better :)

Comment: @Wrikken, you're probably right!

Comment: You don't need to constantly instantiate a new curl for every loop iteration. Do that outside the loop along with the useragent/returntransfer options, and just change the URL inside the loop. Curl objects can be reused for multiple requests. As well, never assume the curl exec succeeded as you are. Always check if it returns FALSE (ie: failed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because your variable is called `$achievementxml` and not `$achievement`.

I would advise you to code with `error_reporting=E_ALL` so you can catch errors like this. Undefined variables will result in an `E_NOTICE` level error message.

Comment: +1, when developing, you can even use E_ALL | E_STRICT to get maximum verbosity.

Comment: Aha, it would appear that I am an idiot. Thanks, and thanks for the advice. I'm quite new to PHP as you might be able to tell, and I'm probably not helping matters by keeping my code completely devoid of comments, but there you have it!

Comment: Or the shortcut: `-1` (which would set all bits), so possibly even new thought op E_* constants in future, until we get a E_REALLY_ALL